# How can I get fs.rename to rename files correctly with different file extensions?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a directory of files named like so:

```
//1-BLUE-RED-ITEM-.gif
//2-GREEN-ORANGE-ITEM-.png
//3-PINK-GREEN-ITEM-.gif
//ETC..
```

I need to rename all of the files in the directory to just the number preceding the rest of the file name and also need to keep the file extensions for obvious reasons. So the new file names should be like so:

```
//1.gif
//2.png
//3.gif
//4.png
//ETC..
```

Here is my code right now, it is saving metadata separately but results are the same no matter how I test. Renames only 9 images.

```
const reNameImages = async(file, batchNumber, fileNum) => {
  fs.renameSync(batchNumber + "/" + file, batchNumber + "/" + fileNum + file.slice(-4), function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Error" + (err));
    }
  });
  console.log("File Renamed:");
  console.log(file);
}

const secondRenameImages = async(batchNumber, thisFile) => {
  let fileNum = thisFile;
  fs.readdirSync(batchNumber).forEach(file => {
    if (file.includes(fileNum)) {
      reNameImages(file, batchNumber, fileNum);
    }
  });
}


const saveMetaDataFiles = async(fileAmount, batchNumber) => {
  var thisCount = 1;
  for (let i = thisCount; i <= fileAmount; i++) {
    saveMetaDataSingleFile(i);
    secondRenameImages(batchNumber, i);
    thisCount++;
  }
};
```

I have tried using `readdir(_directory).forEach` with `fs.renameSync` `fsPromises.rename`, I have tried splitting the file name storing it in an array and cycling through the nested array and returning the 0 index, nothing has succeeded so far except for 9 files, the process always exits before renaming all of the files and can only rename 9 of them. I have tried using async functions and awaiting the rename but no luck. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please show what you tried.

Comment: I have posted the code, thank you.

Comment: I don't think it matters, but why are the functions declared `async` when they never use `await`?

Comment: When `fileNum` is `1`, `file.includes(fileNum)` will be true when the filename contains 10, 11, 21, etc. So `fileNum=1` will rename all those files to `1.extension`

Comment: Use `if (file.startsWith(fileNum + '-'))` so `1` only matches `1-XXX`

Comment: Honestly I've been trying to go back and forth between async functions and not async so much that I have forgotten to change them a couple of times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your condition for matching the file isn't specific enough. It looks for `fileNum` anywhere in the filename, so it will match if it's just part of the number prfix, or even if the number isn't a prefix.

Add the `-` after the number, and look for it only at the beginning with `startsWith()`.

```
const secondRenameImages = async(batchNumber, thisFile) => {
  let fileNum = thisFile + '-';
  fs.readdirSync(batchNumber).forEach(file => {
    if (file.startWith(fileNum)) {
      reNameImages(file, batchNumber, fileNum);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I don't know how but I don't remember seeing a `startsWith()` function anywhere. This worked!